# I am standalone spark cluster , can we use map reduce compress related properties and if used those really works?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am standalone spark cluster , can we use map reduce compress related properties and if used those really works ? i mean in standalone environment map reduce related compress related really works ?

```
config.setProperty("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true");
        config.setProperty("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", "snappy");

        config.setProperty("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true");
        config.setProperty("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", "snappy");
        config.setProperty("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory");
```

Answer (score 0):

Compression properties are not related with cluster properties. You can use any compression type.

If you are going to write it to S3, last property also works but it will not be effective if you use it in local/hdfs storage.